# What's the difference between compression by a gas/liquid or by a solid?

Tags: pressure, everyday-life

Atmospheric pressure is about $1atm$, that is $\approx 10^5 N/m^2$, that is, if $g = 9.8m/s^2$ we get a weight of $\approx 10.339 tons/m^2$. And yet, nobody feels like carrying 10 tons of stuff above their shoulders. (Or maybe, I should say 17~19 tons because [our total surface area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_surface_area#Average_values). Maybe ~1 ton above shoulders considering 1%.)

Sure sure, same pressure is acting on all points, resulting in an equilibrium. Thus, lets focus on an uniform compression. Compressing someone with 10tons of solid weight certainly should kill (indeed, a car weights from $1.5$ to $2$ tons). And yet, it would simply be $\approx 2atm$ (atmosphere + weight), which people can easily survive (and hardly feel) if these $2atm$ were atmospheric pressure, or underwater pressure.

In addition, a human being crushed by $180Kg\approx 1764N\approx 980 Pa\approx 9.67\cdot 10^{-3} atm$ is already enough to cause death by suffocation in minutes. And certainly, one would *feel* the weight, something it doesn't happen if gas pressure is increased, or if $10m$ below water (2 atm).

Why? What's the difference between $1atm$ of a gas/liquid and $1atm$ of a solid-thing compressing/crushing someone/something? Shouldn't they have the same effect and be indistinguishable?

Comment: I suspect that maybe perhaps it has something to do with a non null deviatoric stress tensor? I tried to think in a situation with a null deviatoric tensor involving solids, but I couldn't.

Comment: The pressure is the same in both cases.  What you don't seem to be considering is that people have internal pressurization that is well suited for 1 atm air.  Someone compressed by a mass has the 1 atm air _plus_ the forces due to the mass acting on them.  If you put a $1m$ x$ 1 m $ plate on your body, pressurized the top to 1 atm and created a vacuum below, it would hurt.

Comment: it's because "same pressure is acting on all points, resulting in an equilibrium" with a gas/liquid and not with a solid thing. it doesn't matter if it's 1 atm or 2 atm it's still not dangerous because "same pressure is acting on all points, resulting in an equilibrium"